# How to convert VueJS DemoGrid .vue files to a no-build HTML

Tags: vue.js

https://vuejs.org/examples/#grid

I'm trying to use this simple DemoGrid at VueJs, but without a build step ie without any .vue files - commonly known as the "no build" version.

I just need to know what combination of html/js/css/template conversion etc I need in order to render exactly the same thing.

I have started trying to do this using this guide to [understanding components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html)

I think I can work out how to start using a component using `'no-build` but do not understand what conversions are required to render the component `Grid.vue`

I will include my attempts, though, with such a common example, I would expect someone would have already done this - be it in a blog or tutorial - which I have not yet managed to find.

Comment: `I will include my attempts` would be nice to have those. If you don't want a build tool (why this btw?), you will basically need to use it as CDN. Not sure if there is a place in the current docs but it would come down to something similar [as this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering). Be careful, the link here is for Vue2, so you'll need to convert for Vue3 specific things.

Comment: My bad, this is probably a better link: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools